# puts statements in repl.rb are not printed to logs/log.txt

Tags: ruby, dragonruby-game-toolkit

While going through the dragon ruby documentation here: http://docs.dragonruby.org.
It says

> All puts statements will also be saved to logs/log.txt. So if you want
> to stay in your editor and not look at the terminal, or the DragonRuby
> Console, you can tail this file.

However when I write puts statements, this is the output in logs

> - INFO: Marked app/repl.rb for reload

Answer (score 1):

The puts logs are available in **logs/puts.txt** file.

Looks like the documentation was not updated. Raised PR for the same: https://github.com/DragonRuby/dragonruby-game-toolkit-contrib/pull/83